# linking to different parts of HTML page no longer working after linking to javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

I've linked to this "custom scrollbar" javascript code and used it on my page: [Page link](http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar)

Now, the bottom link here doesn't work anymore.

```
<div class="left" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com/';"><p>&lsaquo;</p></div>
<div class="right" onclick="location.href='#';"><p>&rsaquo;</p></div>
```

Am I doing something wrong or is that a possible natural consequence of using that code?

Here is a link to the site in progress, the 'right button' and the footers are links to '#' [link](http://zoidzoid.altervista.org/Zzzzz_Website_111111_scrollbars.html)

Comment: why are you using onclick events to change link when there is an anchor tag `<a>` exactly for that purpose?

Comment: Because that changes the entire div to a clickable area. I came across it somewhere and decided to use that.

Comment: if you surround the div in an a tag it'll do the same thing

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know/forgot about that.